# Dúvida com recursividade

Tags: java, recursão

Fiz teste de mesa mas o resultado nunca dará `0` porque subtrai `1` de `n` mas depois soma o resultado com `n`.
O resultado dessa questão foi `36` e não entendi porquê.

```
public class Recursivo{

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int result = sum(8);

        System.out.println(result);
    }

    public static int sum(int n){
        if( n == 0){
            return 0;
        }
        else
        {
            return n + sum( n - 1);
        }
    }
}
```

O que realmente faz isso?

```
return n + sum( n - 1);
```

Comment: Porque haja que deve dar `0`?

Comment: Ele chega em 0 sim. A linha que vc está em dúvida que é a mais importante, ali que chama a função recursiva.
O 0 é o ponto de parada, ele subtrai o número informado de 1 em 1 até chegar a 0.

Comment: @GeorgeWurthmann O AP se refere ao resultado de `n + sum( n - 1);`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
return n + sum( n - 1):
```

Nesta linha é somado o valor de `n` com o valor resultante do método `sum(n-1)`.

No exemplo:

```
sum(8) = 8 + sum(7)
sum(7) = 7 + sum(6)
sum(6) = 6 + sum(5)
sum(5) = 5 + sum(4)
sum(4) = 4 + sum(3)
sum(3) = 3 + sum(2)
sum(2) = 2 + sum(1)
sum(1) = 1 + sum(0)
sum(0) = 0.
```

Repare que `sum(0)` não chama o método `sum` novamente. Este é o ponto de parada do método recursivo. Quando a recursividade encontra o ponto de parada, é só voltar toda a cadeia para ir somando os valores e obter o retorno.

Com isso substitui-se os valores:

```
sum(0) = 0.
sum(1) = 1 + sum(0) = 1 + 0  = 1
sum(2) = 2 + sum(1) = 2 + 1  = 3
sum(3) = 3 + sum(2) = 3 + 3  = 6
sum(4) = 4 + sum(3) = 4 + 6 = 10
sum(5) = 5 + sum(4) = 5 + 10 = 15
sum(6) = 6 + sum(5) = 6 + 15 = 21
sum(7) = 7 + sum(6) = 7 + 21 = 28
sum(8) = 8 + sum(7) = 8 + 28 = 36
```

Analisando o método `sum` mais de perto, ele faz a soma de todos os números de `1` até `n`, no exemplo dado: `1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7 + 8 = 36`

Comment: Ótima resposta, em especial o primeiro exemplo que deixou bem claro que as chamadas dos métodos vão se empilhando até que ele retorne algo e interrompa a recurssão, +1

Comment: Ahnnnnn ENTENDI

Answer (score 7):

> O que realmente faz isso?
>
> ```
> return n + sum( n - 1);
> ```

O método `sum()` fica se chamando sempre passando como parâmetro o próprio número que recebeu como argumento menos um, até que esse número chegue a zero que será quando ele retornará zero. Ou seja, se você passar o número 8, ele vai retornar 8 mais o retorno do método `sum(7)`, que vai retornar 7 mais o retorno do método `sum(6)`, que vai retornar 6 mais o retorno do método `sum(5)`, que vai retornar 5 mais.... até chegar a 0, ou seja, cada vez que você chama o método `sum()`, ele soma esse valor com todos os seus valores inferiores até chegar a zero.

Para o caso em questão o retorno ficaria: `8 + 7 + 6 + 5 + 4 + 3 + 2 + 1 + 0`, ou seja: `36`.

Para tentar debugar, coloquei uns `prints` para mostrar o que acontece em cada iteração:

```
public class Recursivo{

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int result = sum(8);

        System.out.println("Resultado final: " + result);
    }

    public static int sum(int n){
        if( n == 0){
            System.out.println("Fim da recursividade");
            return 0;
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("O valor de n nessa iteração é: " + n);
            int ret =  n + sum( n - 1);
            System.out.println("O valor a ser retornado nessa iteração é: " + ret);
            return ret;
        }
    }
}
```

Resultado:

> O valor de n nessa iteração é: 8
> O valor de n nessa iteração é: 7
> O valor de n nessa iteração é: 6
> O valor de n nessa iteração é: 5
> O valor de n nessa iteração é: 4
> O valor de n nessa iteração é: 3
> O valor de n nessa iteração é: 2
> O valor de n nessa iteração é: 1
> Fim da recursividade
> O valor a ser retornado nessa iteração é: 1
> O valor a ser retornado nessa iteração é: 3
> O valor a ser retornado nessa iteração é: 6
> O valor a ser retornado nessa iteração é: 10
> O valor a ser retornado nessa iteração é: 15
> O valor a ser retornado nessa iteração é: 21
> O valor a ser retornado nessa iteração é: 28
> O valor a ser retornado nessa iteração é: 36
> Resultado final: 36

Perceba que existem dois `prints` dentro do `else` no método `sum()`, mas somente o primeiro é mostrado até que seja atingido o ponto final da recursividade, que é quando `n` chega a `0`, e ao invés de chamar o próprio método novamente ele simplesmente retorna um valor.

Comment: Sim, mas ele está somando n + sum( n - 1); Não entendi porque ele soma...

Comment: Sim, ele soma `n`,  que no caso é `8`, com o valor que retornar uma nova chamada ao método `sum()`, que no caso vai ser `sum(7)`, que por sua vez vai fazendo novas chamadas, até que vai somar com `0` e vai para de chamar o método `sum()`. Vou tentar explicar melhor na resposta.