# Como ocorre a recursividade no código a seguir

Tags: java

Gostaria de entender, pois não consigo vislumbrar mentalmente como ocorre no trecho: return fat *  fatorial.fatorar(fat-1);, a questão da recursividade, no que concerne as chamadas do próprio método fatorar em relação a multiplicação com o fat.

```
public class FatorialRecursiva
{   
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
       FatorialRecursiva fatorial = new FatorialRecursiva();
       double dado = 5.0;
       dado = fatorial.fatorar(dado);

       System.out.print(dado);
   }

   public double fatorar(double fat)
   {
       if (fat < 2)
       {
           return 1;
       }else
       {
           return fat *  fatorar(fat-1);
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: Ele cria uma outra instância pra resolver o "subproblema", que por sua vês, cria outra, e assim vai .... A definição de recursão não é necessariamente, "um método chamar ele mesmo"

Comment: essas instâncias não tem sentido...   a recursividade vai acontecer, mas de um jeito não recomendado..

Comment: Daniel Omine como falei em outro cometário, não tinha percebido que havia instanciado a classe tanto no método main quanto no fatorar, corrigi e espero que agora esteja correto.

Comment: @BrunoSilva Se quiser entender melhor como funciona a execução passo-a-passo de uma função/método `recursivo` aqui um exemplo: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/111520/d%C3%BAvida-com-recursividade *Obs - Deve-se tomar muito cuidado com funções/métodos recursivos, pois podem entrar em _loop infinito_ facilmente!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Aqui tem um gif que ajuda a entender tranquilamente:

[image: http://www.cienciacomputacao.com.br]

Comment: O gif apresentou justamente o que eu buscava como resposta. Obrigado a todos pelas contribuições.

Comment: Um gif vale mais do que mil palavras, parabéns, ótima resposta. +1

Comment: Excelent Gif. Havendo maior curiosidade no assunto, sugiro também que você estude os procedimentos de avaliação de código. Eu tinha dificuldade em visualizar isso e entender melhor como o código é avaliado 'mudou minha vida'. Sugiro esse capítulo de um livro clássico: [The Elements of Programming](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-10.html#%_sec_1.1.3) do livro Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs. Este e o próximo capítulo dão uma otima visão sobre o tema.

Answer (score 0):

Basicamente o que acontece é que um método executa ele mesmo. Como a programação está orientada a objetos, a execução do código não é toda linear e possibilita executar um mesmo trecho de código várias vezes.

Recomendo a leitura do artigo em que retirei o trecho abaixo, que usa como exemplo justamente o código que você usou na pergunta:

"[A recursividade trabalha de forma similar a um laço de repetição, na verdade tudo que fazemos em laço, pode ser feito em recursividade. A recursividade é nada mais nada menos do que uma função dentro da outra e ela deve ser pensada como uma pilha.](http://www.linhadecodigo.com.br/artigo/3316/recursividade-em-java.aspx)"

Comment: Acho que não é bem isso, acredito que a duvida esteja exatamente no fato de um método não executar ele mesmo, e ainda assim, ser uma solução recursiva. Cada método instância um novo objeto, da mesma classe, e delega para o método desse objeto a tarefa de resolver o subproblema. Um "this.fatorial", no lugar de "fatorial.fatorial" seria um método executando ele mesmo, e ao meu ver, ainda seria um código OO.

Comment: O método executa ele mesmo quando no segundo return: `return fat *  fatorial.fatorar(fat-1);`. Eu acredito que ele ainda não entende bem como a recursividade funciona e está justamente tentando entender isso com a pergunta, principalmente quando disse "não consigo vislumbrar mentalmente".

Comment: Agora entendi seu pronto da recursividade, mas não concordo. Pra mim o mesmo método de instância de classe diferentes são iguais, entende?

Comment: Não, fatorial recebe uma nova instância: " FatorialRecursiva fatorial = new FatorialRecursiva();", ou seja, tecnicamente, é outro método. Pelo que comprendi da pergunta, ele não consegue mentalmente visualizar como ocorre a chamada de um método, dentro do próprio método, na linha que ele citou. A resposta é simples. Não há essa chamada, é outro método, de outro objeto. Porem, pelo menos para mim, isso ainda é uma solução recursiva para um problema. Implementado de uma forma menos eficiente.

Comment: Objetos diferentes instanciados da mesma classe, possuem métodos diferentes. Não acho que esteja correto afirmar que são iguais, só por que nesse caso, vão ter o mesmo comportamento.

Comment: Bem o modo como eu postei o código pode estar trazendo um pouco de confusão no entanto agora percebi que eu instanciei a classe tanto no método main quanto no método fatorar, porém vejo isso como incorreto, era pra eu ter instanciado somente no método main, vou corrigir. E no caso minha duvido está em realmente como se dá a recursividade.